# Full width material-ui Button within a Badge?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-design, material-ui

I have a Button inside a Grid and was using `fullWidth` to expand it to fill the container.

This worked fine, until I wrapped it in a Badge. Now the fullWidth property is ignored and the button is default width.

Worked fine:

```
<Button variant={"outlined"} color={"secondary"} fullWidth>
    Todo
</Button>
```

Now not working:

```
<Badge badgeContent={4} color={"secondary"}>
    <Button variant={"outlined"} color={"secondary"} fullWidth>
        Todo
    </Button>
</Badge>
```

How can I get the button to expand to fill its parent?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid/Grid";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button/Button";
import Badge from "@material-ui/core/Badge/Badge";


export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (

            <Grid container style={{margin: 10}}>
                <Grid item xs={2}>

                    <Badge badgeContent={4} color={"secondary"}>
                        <Button variant={"outlined"} color={"secondary"} fullWidth>
                            Todo badge
                        </Button>
                    </Badge>

                    <Button variant={"outlined"} color={"secondary"} fullWidth>
                        Todo no badge
                    </Button>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={10}>

                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        );
    }
};
```

Answer (score 5):

you have to apply fullWidth property to badge

```js
<Badge badgeContent={4} color={"secondary"} fullWidth>
    <Button variant={"outlined"} color={"secondary"}>
        Todo
    </Button>
</Badge>
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. (Sorry, should have mentioned I tried this)

Comment: Did you try adding it to badge?

Comment: Yes, exactly as you suggest.

Comment: check in dev tools is badge width is fullWidth or not? If it is fullWidth and button width is not fullWidth then apply fullWidth property for both.

Comment: Even if I apply it to both elements, it doesn't work. Are you guessing here, or is this working for you locally?

Comment: its working for me. may be some parent classes doing this.

Comment: I’ve included a failing example in my question.

Answer (score 3):

Just add this property: fullWidth={true}

```
import { Button } from "@mui/material";
 <Button
          variant="contained"
          fullWidth={true}
          type="submit"
        >
          Click me
        </Button>
```

docs:
https://mui.com/api/button/

Answer (score 2):

One easy way is to use the `sx` prop on the `Badge` to set the `width` to `'100%'`.

```
<Badge sx={{ width: '100%' }} variant="dot" color="primary" badgeContent={1}>
  <Button fullWidth variant="contained"  color="neutral">
    Button
  </Button>
</Badge>
```

And make sure you have `fullWidth` set on the `Button`

Answer (score 1):

I could come up with a solution using width CSS property:

here is my answer:

```
const styles = theme => ({
  margin: {
    margin: theme.spacing.unit * 2,
    width: '100%'
  }
});

function SimpleBadge(props) {
  const { classes } = props;
  return (
    <Grid container>
      <Grid item xs={11}>
      <Badge color="primary" badgeContent={4} className={classes.margin} >
        <Button variant="contained" fullWidth>Button</Button>
      </Badge>

      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

please find that I have used `width: '100%'` in badge styles.

here is a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/wqm9kmxmql

hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

The `width` property needs to be applied to the root component (`.MuiBadge-root`) that holds both the actual badge and its child (the button in your example).

You can customize its style in various ways. Here I'm using `styled`:

```jsx
const MyBadge = styled(Badge)({
  width: '100%'
})

<MyBadge badgeContent="1" color="secondary">
  <Button variant="contained" color="primary" fullWidth>
    Hello World
  </Button>
</MyBadge>
```

[Working example on CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-thunder-x50ue4?file=/index.js:279-440)